# Left Join With a Where Clause on Left Table

Tags: mysql

I want to filter my SQL results between two given dates while also joining a table on a condition. This is the SQL I'm currently using:

```
select
   event.location,
   event.dt,
   event.start
from event
where
   event.dt BETWEEN "2014-02-01" AND "2014-02-04"
   left join entity on entity.id = event.entity
   order by dt desc;
```

If I move the `event.dt BETWEEN` to the join (i.e., on `entity.id = . . . and event.dt BETWEEN`), it doesn't appear to filter the results at all, returning me a ton of results outside of the date range specified.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: WHERE goes after the JOINs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the join like so

```
select  event.location, 
        event.dt, 
        event.start 
from    event left join 
        entity on entity.id = event.entity
where   event.dt BETWEEN "2014-02-01" AND "2014-02-04" 
order by dt desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be like this

```
select
   event.location,
   event.dt,
   event.start
from event
   left join entity on entity.id = event.entity
where
   event.dt BETWEEN "2014-02-01" AND "2014-02-04"
   order by event.dt desc;
```